# SVG resizing without affecting line thickness with css without editing the SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I am new here so I hope I'll explain myself clearly.
I created a React SvgIcon component, but I am having an issue with SVG size. I got all my SVG icons in 16x16, my component should accept a 'size' prop to change the SVG dimension.
When size is equal to 'large', the SVG should be 24x24.

What I would like to have
[correct SVG dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBI2t.png)

What I got changing the SVG 's width/height
[what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEuue.png)

I don't want the line's thickness to change. Is possible to get the correct result with CSS/SCSS?

Comment: Perhaps specify the stroke width in pixels instead of user units. Can you post the working svg image in the live snippet?

Comment: try using `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` for the line